# If term and page have the same slug, how can I view the term archive?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect, rewrite-rules

I am using a custom taxonomy with the term slug 'nursery'. I'm also using a page with the slug 'nursery'. I can view the *page* fine, but trying to view the 'nursery' term archive page as fetched by `get_term_link()` just redirects me back to the page.

So, from this page:
/all-classes/nursery

I have a link to
/class/nursery

But clicking on the link just redirects me back to
/all-classes/nursery

instead of showing me the archive page.

How can I view the archive page for that term?

Edit: code, as requested.

```
class Taxonomy {

  public $taxonomies;

  function __construct() {
    $this->taxonomies = $this->set_taxonomies();
    add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'register_taxonomies'));
  }

  // Register our taxonomies
  public function register_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('class', 'post', $this->taxonomies['class']);
  }

  private function set_taxonomies() {
    return array(
      'class' => array(
        'public'        => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
          //'slug' => 'class-blog',
          'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'labels' => array(
          'name'                       => _x( 'Classes', 'taxonomy general name', 'pys' ),
          'singular_name'              => _x( 'Class', 'taxonomy singular name', 'pys' ),
          'search_items'               => __( 'Search Classes', 'pys' ),
          'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Classes', 'pys' ),
          'all_items'                  => __( 'All Classes', 'pys' ),
          'parent_item'                => null,
          'parent_item_colon'          => null,
          'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Class', 'pys' ),
          'update_item'                => __( 'Update Class', 'pys' ),
          'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Class', 'pys' ),
          'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Class Name', 'pys' ),
          'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate classes with commas', 'pys' ),
          'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove classes', 'pys' ),
          'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used classes', 'pys' ),
          'not_found'                  => __( 'No classes found.', 'pys' ),
          'menu_name'                  => __( 'Classes', 'pys' ),
        ),
      ), // end of 'channel' taxonomy
    );
  }
}
```

Slightly modified version to remove irrelevant stuff. The Taxonomy class is instantiated when functions.php is run.

Comment: Can you show the code that register the custom taxonomy? I can not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Code added - the fact that you can't reproduce it seems hopeful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, resolved this.

I am now registering the taxonomy and terms on the `init` hook rather than `wp_loaded` and that seems to have fixed things.

I will accept this answer as soon as I can.